# Using the Spotify iOS SDK, how can I tell what market the user is connected to?

Tags: spotify

Is it possible to tell the country associated with the current user's account with the iOS Spotify SDK?   How?  I have not been able to find anything in [the docs](https://developer.spotify.com/ios-sdk-docs/Documents/index.html).

(I'd like to get the ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 country code so that another (unauthenticated) user can do searches with the web api and only find tracks that we will ultimately be able to play using the authenticated user that is using the SDK.)

Answer (score 0):

Found it.  It is available from the `territory` field of the `SPTUser` object.  Here is how you might get it after having logged in and received a `session` object, example code in Swift:

```
SPTUser.requestCurrentUserWithAccessToken(session.accessToken) { error, object in        
    guard let user = object as? SPTUser,
              territory = user.territory else {
        print("Could not get territory, error: \(error)"
        return
    }
    print(territory)
}
```

However, you will get nil values for the territory unless you have included `SPTAuthUserReadPrivateScope` in `requestedScopes` when setting up your `SPTAuth` object.